# Facebook login error : URL Blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have used javascript SDK for facebook login v2.8.
my facebook login properly but today I get an error message

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login is on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

can anyone help me to solve out because I don't know javascript SDK need redirect URL or not?

and if I am not login in facebook in a current browser it shows me

> Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.

Expected behavior need to show facebook login page

Comment: @DanWilson but javascript sdk not require redirect uri